# Getting a job in Germany as a fresh university graduate (Bachelor of Arts - Anglistics)

Tags: career-path, germany, bachelor, assistant-professor

everyone!

My wife and I just recently moved to Germany (November last year) from Serbia and ever since then, we've been on the hunt for new opportunities!

My wife pretty easily got through the *Annerkennung* process for her field (Health Industry) after having completed a couple of courses and done a couple of translations of her degree.

I'm a fresh graduate, have completed a BA in English Language and literature and I'm due to have my degree recognized here. After contacting the relevant office for my region, I've been told that I need the following:

- C2 level of **German** language
- Translation of all of my degrees, verified by the competent authority
- Description and grades from all the courses taken.

(This may or may not be 100% true, [since the site I've been referred to from the office for this information didn't work at the time of posting this question](https://www.bezreg-detmold.nrw.de/wir-ueber-uns/organisationsstruktur/abteilung-4/dezernat-46), so I just typed everything as I remember seeing it)

My questions are, to anyone that's gone through this process or has any experience in the same field:

1. What comes next after obtaining C2 in German language? This is an extremely high bar to reach, so I've asked, emailed and contacted numerous institutions and people, and I've been getting totally different information about this for months now. Are there any additional exams, schooling?
2. **Is it worth it?** This is a controversial question, but since getting vague answers from so many people and not seeing many ads for a position of a teacher/professor at schools or private institutions, one asks himself if his degree holds any value at all. Reaching C2 in any language can be extremely challenging and time consuming. By this, I mean, is the W-scale reserved for the PhD holders only? If so, what can a fresh graduate hope for, in terms of pay and job availability?
3. Which job can one hope for? Usually, bachelor degree holders can work as a freelance contractors, but I'm specifically referring to the full-time (Vollzeit) job availability. Elementary schools, high schools, translators?

Another thing that I should mention is that I've taken a course a while back (as a plan B) in web development (unfortunately, haven't finished it due to the lack of funds) and I'm asking if I should switch careers if it proves that this whole process is just simply not worth it.

I apologize for the lengthy first post, I wish you all a wonderful weekend and thank you for all the helpful answers!

Best regards,
Nemanja

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? Are you asking about getting into a PhD programme? If you are asking more generally about getting a non academic job in Germany, this is not the right place to ask since we're focused on academia here.

Comment: What exactly do you need the C2 for? To get your degree recognized? That doesn't seem right. To get a job? That would depend on the job, wouldn't it? Not all jobs require C2. It this for a specific job? If so, which kind?

Comment: @NemanjaRitan A job in academia? If not, this is not the right place to ask.

Comment: @GrotesqueSI, Not a problem, I'll clarify a bit. I'm interested in landing a job here (Germany) Since I'm unable to work in schools and my application receives an auto deny (since my bachelors degree is from the third world countries (Serbia)), I have to "equalize" it or have it go through Annerkenung process to be equal to a German one.

Comment: @Sursula-they- I'll include a short transcript here from the email from the Annerkenung office:

"Ich weise darauf hin, dass eine Antragstellung bei mir ohne Nachweis über C 2-Deutschkenntnisse nicht möglich ist." That is ONLY for my degree to be recognized in DE. 

I'm specifically asking about job opportunities (does an English professor in Germany have any) and similar experiences with people that completed the studies outside of the EU, gone through the Annerkenung process, that had success finding a job in their field in Germany.

Comment: @NemanjaRitan From the website is seems that you are trying to get Anerkennung for Lehramt, not for your degree in general. The difference is, recognizing a degree from another country and recognizing this degree qualifies you to be a teacher. In Germany, just because you studied math, you cannot be a math teacher, the same goes for any other subject. You have to study to become a teacher. And to be a teacher (at a German school), you need to speak German (C2).

Comment: @Sursula-they- Thank you for the clarification! Makes sense, since this degree qualifies me for a teaching position in schools or private institutions in my home country without additional training and/or qualifications.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place to ask; it would be the right place to ask only if you were asking about qualifying for a job (or graduate admissions) at a university (or other institution of higher education)

Comment: I agree with the others, unfortunately. Our role is to answer questions about "academia," which we define as post-graduate degrees and academic careers (research, teaching college, etc.). Jobs as a schoolteacher, web developer, or translator are outside of our purview; we simply don't have expertise to share with you. Your questions about getting Germany to recognize your degree (and whether C2 is needed for this) may be something we can help with; if we haven't already addressed that question, feel free to repost that one separately.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer some aspects of your question:

- Having a degree in a subject that is also taught in schools does not (automatically) qualify you to teach in Germany. Here, you normally study those subjects in a special teacher path ("auf Lehramt") that will include some teaching skills in the curriculum.
- a BA degree alone is normally not enough in Germany to become a teacher, you will need a MA as well (and a learning period at a school afterward called "Referendariat")
- if you plan on working as a teacher, you should consider a MA together with a German course to reach C2 level
- teaching at schools and teaching at universities are two completely different things. W stage is only for university professors, and you will need at least a PhD (and a MA before the PhD) and in most cases also another qualification called "Habilitation"
- teachers are payed according to TvöD, at elementary schools typically at E11 and at secondary schools E13. In some Bundesländer, you will get "verbeamted" when becoming a teacher.
- If you don't want to work as an official teacher at a school, I highly, highly doubt that you will need a C2 level of German just to get your degree officially recognized. But you will need to go somewhere else to to that than the place that only focuses on teachers (the link you provided). See [here](https://www.anerkennung-in-deutschland.de/html/de/hochschule.php#) for more info.
- in some places (like Berlin), you might be able to become a teacher (C2 will still apply!!) without going the official BA-MA-Referendariat route as a so called "Quereinsteiger", but as far as I know that only works if you have a masters (and they will only take you if they don't have any regular teachers to employ, most Quereinsteiger are from STEM subjects)

Comment: Aren't teachers typically "Beamte", rather than being paid according to TVöD? Also, it might be worth mentioning that even with a full teacher's education from abroad, you might still have to go through the Referendariat (in fact, this might even be the case if you move between different German states.)